# iOS: Does a pairing window always display when connecting to a BLE device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to avoid the BLE pairing pop up window on iOS when connecting to a small disposable device. The device will only be used once. If the device is advertising for its lifetime (no more than a few minutes) and does not require encrypted communication. Will an app that I develop be able to directly communicate with the device without displaying a pairing popup?

Comment: If there is a way to avoid it I never found it.

Answer (score 1):

The pairing pop up is only shown if a characteristic specifies that encryption is required.  If no encryption is specified by the peripheral then no pairing dialog is shown.

If you aren't getting the behaviour you desire, you need to change your peripheral or not access the encrypted characteristic from your central.

Answer (score 0):

If you pair the devices, then the user must accept that. But if you just connect and communicate with GATT characteristics that don't need pairing, you don't need to pair and hence no popup.